# Chef - Mount - how to add persistence (/p:yes)

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I want to mount a network drive using chef on a windows machine, the cmd I want to simulate is

```
net use z: \\path\to\drive /u:user@domain password /p:yes
```

Im using the mount resource:

```
mount 'Z:' do
  action :mount
  device drive_path
  username user
  domain domain
  password password
  fstype 'nfs'
end
```

my problem is I don't know (and couldn't find in the documentation) how to add the **/persistent:yes**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't actually use the `net use` CLI, instead it calls the `NetUseAdd` Win32 API, and I'm not actually sure if that flag is even available on that call. Might need to use a different call? My Windows-fu is too weak to know the specifics but I'm pretty sure the answer is "you can't change it, what you see is what you get".